# What is async and await and when would you use these in windows development?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have always seen the keywords async used in Silverlight but was wondering if there is someone with a dummy's explanation of what it is and when to use it and its benefits. Please if you can explain, will be greatly appreciative. Thank you.

Comment: This comes up a lot with threading  This is a pretty big topic, but if you just want a basic practical one sentence answer, asynchronous means that two things happen in time independent of each other.  For instance, you have a button that queries a database.  If you don't go out of your way to make it asynchronous, your entire program is going to stop and wait for that to finish before allowing you to do anything else.  If you don't want that to happen, you can make it asynchronous (usually by using another thread), and still retain control of your UI, for example.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt it bears mention that one of the main points of async/await is *to avoid having to spawn new threads*.  See, for example, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx , which says in part "The whole point of async methods it that you stay on the current thread as much as possible."

Comment: @phoog - Spawning threads is not the same as staying on the correct thread.

Comment: @Erno yes, that's exactly the point of my comment.

Comment: @phoog - " it bears mention that one of the main points of async/await is to avoid having to spawn new threads." I do not agree with this. async/await is for easily coding and reading asynchronous calls/callbacks. That's it. We can do without. Don't get me wrong; I love these keywords.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.infosupport.com/c-5-0-async-explained-as-simple-as-possible/), it gives a nice introduction and explanation of what async and await are.

If you want to really understand it, have a look at [Jon Skeet's series on async and await](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/05/08/eduasync-part-1-introduction/)

Comment: The first link "this blog post" is amazingly clear and useful. Clarified a lot of things.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 15):

Start with [my introductory article in MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456401.aspx).

And then read [the papers on the async CTP site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx).

And then read [these fifteen articles:](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/async/).

If you still have questions after all that, try asking at [the async forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/threads).

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Makyen: I encourage you to write an answer that does exactly that. That way we all benefit from your wisdom.

Comment: I'm sure you're better qualified than I am. My comment is intended as more of a nudge to remind you that this is one of the answers that has been affected by the change in SO over the years. It's gone from being perfectly acceptable to being "not an answer" due to being only a collection of links (one of which is dead; before it died it changed significantly after you added it here). The fact that one link is dead is a good example of why it's preferable to include the essentials here.

Comment: A large portion of the problem is that the question is really too broad to cover in a SO Q&A, as exemplified by both answers linking to a not just a single blog post, but each answer links to a different series of posts on the subject.

Comment: @Makyen: Well then feel free to vote to delete this answer if you think it is low quality but you're unable to write a better one.