# Compiler Error Consuming Web API Call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to implement a webapi call into a legacy ASP.Net Web Forms application.
I know not all of the usings are need for this method but they are for other methods on the page i included on the off chance that one of them is causing the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

private string GetToken(string Username, string IpAddress)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(SSOApiUri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/yourcustomobjects").Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            ***var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();***
            var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetSSOTokenResponse>(data);
            result = token.Token;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

When I try to compile my application I get the following error at the emphisized line:

> Error 19  The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.
>   Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing
>   its return type to 'Task< string>'.

I am trying to implement a solution similar to the one found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448690/how-to-consume-a-webapi-from-asp-net-web-api-to-store-result-in-database) but it is failing.  I need to call the WebAPI Method, and return part of the result as a string... not a Task< String>

Comment: That's a pretty open-and-shut case.  What don't you understand?  Did you do any research on async/await when this error popped up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is async and await and when would you use these in windows development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906106/what-is-async-and-await-and-when-would-you-use-these-in-windows-development)

Comment: If I am doing my call wrong that is fine then how do I consume the API Call and return a string from the method?

Comment: I am trying to implement a soluction similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448690/how-to-consume-a-webapi-from-asp-net-web-api-to-store-result-in-database  But the result is failing.

Answer (score 2):

The error is straightforward.  You must have an `async` method to use the `await` keyword. Your return value will automatically be wrapped in a Task as a result by the compiler. Note that the `.Result` can be changed to an await as well. [Here's the Microsoft documentation on the async/await keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

```
private async Task<string> GetToken(string Username, string IpAddress)
{
   string result = string.Empty;

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(SSOApiUri);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/yourcustomobjects");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetSSOTokenResponse>(data);
        result = token.Token;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I need to consume the call and return a string not a task.  The research I did said this was the way to do it.

Comment: If you don't want to use await, then just change your commented out line to `var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` but getting more information about how the async code works will serve you better in the long run.

Comment: Use `GetToken().Result` in the calling function if you want the string, but my last comment will give you the same result.

Comment: Cant I just do JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetSSOTokenResponse>(data.Result); ?

Comment: That is what I said in my first comment under this response, just without keeping your temp variable.